# How to find the exact category of a published article in a multiple-category journal?

Tags: journals, ranking, scopus

I need to find the quartile of a journal(Advances in Space Research) in the specific year that my article was published. I can reach the journal metrics on Scopus and see the quartiles and details. However, the problem is that since 2018, the journal started to list six categories and our article is actually an interdisciplinary study, which falls into three categories at the same time. In that article, we are reporting our studies about some ionospheric measurements. So the article fits in atmospheric science, space and planetary science, and general earth and space science category. According to Scopus, the journal has different rankings/quartiles in all these categories. As the ionosphere is part of the atmosphere, I feel the study is closer to atmospheric science and I am listing it as in the atmospheric sciences category, but I can not be sure if this is correct. The journal web page does not show which category your article belongs to, either. So, does anybody know of a way to tell the exact category of an article? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What does it mean for a journal to have a "quartile"?

Answer (score 2):

None of this matters intrinsically or objectively: what it means to be in a quartile, what it means to be in a given field, etc, are all imposed subjective measures.

You say you "need to find the quartile" but I very much doubt you need to do this for *your own purpose*. Rather, perhaps someone has *requested* that you do this, and in that case, what is most important if you want to make that someone happy is that you provide them information that they are satisfied with. If they have determined that "quartile as defined by Scopus" is the measure they care about, then you have that part of the puzzle solved. The other part is "quartile of what category", so you'll have to either A) Use guidance provided by the person/organization requesting the information in the first place, or B) Use your best judgment of what you think is right or think you can justify if they question your choice. You might find it easier to justify a particular field if the journal organizes papers by field and placed yours in one of these categories, but not all interdisciplinary journals will do such a thing.

In summary, unless you have more specific guidance about how to do this, the category is the category you feel fits best and that you feel you can best justify.